# Change action for existing button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

i would like to change an action from an existing button to a func in my MainTableViewController. If i create the button programmatically, its not a problem - but with an existing button from Storyboard-Editor the method will not be called.

Any ideas what is wrong here?

```
class SignatureTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var signatureButton: UIButton!

    var formVC:FormTableViewController!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override init() {

        super.init()

        self.signatureButton.addTarget(formVC, action: "signatureButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need to change what function the button calls?

You could just have an variable holding the buttons state and have a switch statement to choose the proper behavior for the button.

```
var buttonState : Int = ButtonStates.FIRST_STATE

func buttonCLick(button :UIButton)
{
  switch (buttonState)
    {
      case ButtonStates.FIRST_STATE:
        doMyFirstAction()
        break;
      case ButtonStates.SECOND_STATE:
        doMySecondAction()
        break;
      default;
        break;

  }
}
```

Comment: Upvote because this helped me, but I just wanted to mention that you didn't really answer OP's question. You just gave a workaround.

Comment: Hey if you are interested I could include how to change a button's action target?

Comment: That would be great

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps. I stumbled upon it accidentally.

• Keep both the **Storyboard** and the **ViewController** open.
• Click on the button you want to remap to another function.
• Open the **Utilities** pane on the right and select Connections Inspector (sixth Icon from the left).
• Under Sent Actions, your button would   have been mapped to a function.
• Move the mouse over it and click on the small cross that appears on the left top to remove the function. 
• Click and hold on the small circle near action.
• Drag it to the  fucntion you want to map the button to.

You are Done.

Comment: If I have multiple buttons, say 7 buttons, connected to one shared method `onButtonClick`, now I just want to change the method name to `onButtonTouched`, how to do this easy? It won't work if just changing the method name. Thanks :-)

Comment: Right Click on the method name and select "Refractor" -> "Rename". The screen will show you how many times you have referred to that method in ViewController or Storyboard. Enter the new name for method, it will be updated in all places.